# How to filter items in a vector of Option by converting them to None in place?

Tags: vector, rust

I want to filter out some items in a vector of `Option` and I want to do so in place without creating a new vector, as it could be done with a combination of `map` and `collect`. I do not want to use `Vec::map_in_place` as this is deprecated.

I found the following solution:

```rust
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![
        Some("10".to_owned()),
        Some("5".to_owned()),
        None,
        Some("20".to_owned()),
    ];

    for i in v.iter_mut() {
        let j = match mem::replace(i, None) {
            None => None,
            Some(f) => {
                if f == "20" {
                    None
                } else {
                    Some(f)
                }
            }
        };
        mem::replace(i, j);
    }
    println!("v = {:?}", v);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7d738be48a8c96c890abecdf87868eb3)

Although it works fine, it makes 2 copies for each element, whether the element is modified or not.

Is there a more idiomatic solution that would also require less copying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## After Vladimir's comment

At the risk of massively overfitting the concrete example; the following would also work:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![Some("10".to_owned()), Some("5".to_owned()),
                     None, Some("20".to_owned())];

    for i in v.iter_mut() {
        if i.as_ref().map_or(false, |f| *f == "20") {
            i.take();
        }
    }
    println!("v = {:?}", v);
}
```

## Initial answer

Perhaps you simplified your example too much, but for the given program if can be done with only one copy, and only when a change is needed. The main idea is that you first check whether you need to change (i.e., that `i` is `Some("20")`), and then you simply do the change. A little dance with borrowchk seems necessary, but a solution is as follows:

```
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![Some("10".to_owned()), Some("5".to_owned()),
                     None, Some("20".to_owned())];

    for i in v.iter_mut() {
        // Borrowchk-dance: make sure this borrow of i ends before we try to mutate
        let is_a_twenty = match i {
            &mut Some(ref f) if *f == "20" => true,
            _ => false,
        };
        // Now that we're free to borrow i mutably, go ahead and do so
        if is_a_twenty {
            mem::replace(i, None);
        }

    }
    println!("v = {:?}", v);
}
```

Comment: FYI, `mem::replace(&mut option, None)` is exactly equivalent to `option.take()`, but the latter is more concise and idiomatic.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Good point, but perhaps a bit too specific for the minimal example. Nevertheless, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add that in the current Rust stdlib, iterator has a method `filter_map` that filters out `None` values, so you can skip the `.filter(|x| x.is_some())` step in the chain.

Comment: It will be good if you will say what answer you're referring to, and perhaps even bring a full example.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more direct approaches, one using a for loop and one using an iterator:

```rust
fn g(number_strings: &mut Vec<Option<String>>, target: &str) {
    for some_string in number_strings.iter_mut() {
        if let Some(ref string) = some_string {
            if string == target {
                *some_string = None;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn h(number_strings: &mut Vec<Option<String>>, target: &str) {
    number_strings
        .iter_mut()
        .filter(|s| s.is_some() && s.as_ref().unwrap() == target)
        .for_each(|s| *s = None);
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![
        Some("10".to_owned()),
        Some("5".to_owned()),
        None,
        Some("20".to_owned()),
        Some("10".to_owned()),
        Some("20".to_owned()),
    ];
    println!("{:?}", v);
    g(&mut v, "10");
    println!("{:?}", v);
    h(&mut v, "20");
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Output:

```
[Some("10"), Some("5"), None, Some("20"), Some("10"), Some("20")]
[None, Some("5"), None, Some("20"), None, Some("20")]
[None, Some("5"), None, None, None, None]
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=24e4be25840c30f2f07435b94f585b3d)